# location href returns as undefined

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have this Ripple effect code:

```
(function (window, $) {

  $(function() {


    $('.ripple-white').on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var $div = $('<div/>'),
          btnOffset = $(this).offset(),
            xPos = event.pageX - btnOffset.left,
            yPos = event.pageY - btnOffset.top;



      $div.addClass('ripple-effect');
      var $ripple = $(".ripple-effect");

      $ripple.css("height", $(this).height());
      $ripple.css("width", $(this).height());
      $div
        .css({
          top: yPos - ($ripple.height()/2),
          left: xPos - ($ripple.width()/2),
          background: $(this).data("ripple-color")
        }) 
        .appendTo($(this));

      window.setTimeout(function(){
        $div.remove();
        location.href = $(this).attr('href');
      }, 800);

    });

  });

})(window, jQuery);
```

Which is dynamically used for Wordpress post listing:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=50' ); ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<div class="flex-3col"><a class="ripple-white" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h3 class="single-menu"><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a></div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

For some reason I'm getting the location.href as UNDEFINED. I've also tried:

```
$('a', this).attr("href");
```

Any advice what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` doesn't refers to anchor in [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), You can cache the output in a variable which can be used later.

```
var href = $(this).attr('href'); //Cached the output
window.setTimeout(function(){
  $div.remove();
  location.href = href ;
}, 800);
```

Or, You can pass argument

```
window.setTimeout(function(href){
  $div.remove();
  location.href = href ;
}, 800, $(this).attr('href'));
```

```js
window.setTimeout(function(href) {
  console.log('href', href)
}, 800, window.location.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `this` in variable `self` to clicked element, like this:

```js
(function (window, $) {

  $(function() {


    $('.ripple-white').on('click', function (event) {
 var self = this;
      event.preventDefault();

      var $div = $('<div/>'),
          btnOffset = $(this).offset(),
            xPos = event.pageX - btnOffset.left,
            yPos = event.pageY - btnOffset.top;



      $div.addClass('ripple-effect');
      var $ripple = $(".ripple-effect");

      $ripple.css("height", $(this).height());
      $ripple.css("width", $(this).height());
      $div
        .css({
          top: yPos - ($ripple.height()/2),
          left: xPos - ($ripple.width()/2),
          background: $(this).data("ripple-color")
        }) 
        .appendTo($(this));

      window.setTimeout(function(){
        $div.remove();
        //location.href = $(this).attr('href');
  $(".clicked_href").html( $(self).attr('href') );
      }, 800);

    });

  });

})(window, jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-3col"><a class="ripple-white" href="http://www11.com"><h3 class="single-menu">Link 1</h3></a></div>
<div class="flex-3col"><a class="ripple-white" href="http://www22.com"><h3 class="single-menu">Link 2</h3></a></div>
<div class="flex-3col"><a class="ripple-white" href="http://www33.com"><h3 class="single-menu">Link 3</h3></a></div>

<div>Href: <span class="clicked_href"></span></div>
```